# Are dogs excellent wingmen?

Tags: zoology, dogs

I was just watching the Youtube video [The Science of DOGS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZipzqCphi8s) by the channel [AsapSCIENCE](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCC552Sd-3nyi_tk2BudLUzA). It was a pretty interesting video, but something that really stuck out to me was said in the first 10 seconds of the video. The video's narrator says

> In fact, studies have shown that men are three times more likely to get a girl's phone number if they have a dog by their side.

I looked in the sources part of the video description, but I could not find the studied that this was referencing to (it may be because of a paywall, but I'm not sure how likely that is).

So, is this claim true? Have there been actual studies on this subject? Are dogs awesome [wingmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingman_(social))?

Comment: I'm guessing this is [one of the studies](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2752/175303708X371564#.VcVZb_mqpBc) - does anyone with access to the full study want to answer the question?

Comment: "Researchers proposed that in today’s society, a man having a dog signals that he has the resources and the willingness to care for someone else, even if other evidence of his mating behavior says otherwise" per a Slate article-http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2014/02/dogs_can_help_you_get_a_date_and_look_more_attractive_the_power_of_a_labrador.html.

Comment: Keep in mind that correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: A female over the age of 18 is a woman. A girl is under-age. Is the dog-wielding man trying to get the phone numbers of children? Children are very attracted to animals, so it would be a good strategy.

Comment: OK, I know what my next startup is... Renting dogs to dudes to ask women out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are dogs excellent wingmen?

According to the study, **yes**.  Three times more women gave their phone number to the man when he was accompanied by a friendly dog.

As Oddthinking worked out, it was [one of the studies](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2752/175303708X371564#.Vcc45Caqqkp)

[**Domestic Dogs as Facilitator in Social Interaction: An Evaluation of Helping and Courtship Behaviors**](http://nicolas.gueguen.free.fr/Articles/Anthrozoos2008.pdf)

> **Experiment 4** ... In this experiment,
>   the participants were selected following a random assignment in which the confederate was
>   instructed to approach the first young woman in the relevant age group (18 to 25 years) who
>   was walking alone in the pedestrian zone where the experiment was being carried out. As in
>   the previous experiments, when soliciting the young women the confederate kept his dog on
>   a lead in the experimental condition, whereas he was not accompanied by his dog in the nodog
>   control condition. The same verbal solicitation was made by the confederate in both the
>   control and the experimental conditions:
>
> “Hello. My name’s Antoine. I just want to say that I think you’re really pretty. I have
>   to go to work this afternoon, but I was wondering if you would give me your
>   phone number. I’ll phone you later and we can have a drink together someplace.”
>
> ...
>
> **Results and Discussion**
>   The dependent variable in this experiment was the number of participants who agreed to the
>   courtship request. The results showed that 28.3% (34/120) of the women approached complied
>   with the request when the confederate was with the dog, compared with 9.2% (11/120)
>   of women when the confederate was not with the dog. This difference is significant (²
>   (1) =
>   14.47, n = 240, p < 0.001; r = 0.25)...